# What is Windows actually doing when a program crashes and the message "[Program] is trying to recover your information" appears?

Tags: windows, crash

When a Windows application crashes, a window similar to this appears saying "[ApplicationName] is trying to recover your information"
[image: Application Crash Sample]

What is Windows actually doing during this time? How is it *recovering* my information?

Comment: I guess that it is the application, not the OS kernel, which do the "recovering". But I never used Windows.

Comment: No, it's from Windows. After the application has crashed none of its code can be activated (AFAIK). At this point Windows usually does memory clean-up, but since Windows 7 (maybe Vista as well), the "Information recovery" dialog has started to appear after crashes. This dialog appears for non-Microsoft applications as well.

Comment: I should probably move this question to SuperUser. If you're an admin reading this and can move it, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed some files getting restored to a previous version after the application crashed and this `trying to recover your information` is left to finish what it's doing.

So, after a crash, Windows seems to be using the `System Restore` to "recover" some open files to a previous state, thinking that they might have been corrupted by the crash.

If the `trying to recover your information` window is cancelled, the files remain in their current state at the crash time.